# How to filter users with powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I want to fetch user properties (like SAMNAME, First Name, Last Name etc.) of AD users with specific email ID and then output the same to a CSV file, how this can be done with PowerShell script?

```
Get-ADUser -searchbase $searchLoc -Properties *, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", PasswordNeverExpires -Filter * | Select-Object @{Label = "SAM Account Name";Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}}, @{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}}, @{Label = "Email Address";Expression = {$_.mail}} | Convertto-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "," | %{$_ -replace '"',""} | out-file $reportpath -fo -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: Others have been told that this isn't a script-writing service; please describe what you've tried and what your research shows.

Comment: Hi, there is plenty of help on Google for you. Once you have some code to debug, you can come back here and ask for help.

Comment: How to select AD-Users: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx and how to write in CSV: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ee176825.aspx i won't write the final code since you didn't even try it yourself.

Comment: here is what I've written:  Get-ADUser -searchbase $searchLoc -Properties *, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", PasswordNeverExpires -Filter * |
  Select-Object @{Label = "SAM Account Name";Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}}, 
                @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
                @{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
                @{Label = "Email Address";Expression = {$_.mail}} | Convertto-Csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "," | %{$_ -replace '"',""} | out-file $reportpath -fo -Encoding ascii

Comment: I suggest you take your last comment and make it an edit to the original question.  That way people who visit will easily see what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 Get-ADUser -Filter "*" | where UserPrincipalName -eq "test@domain.fr" | select name, surname, SamAccountName
```

Comment: Vote++ for actually helping the OP.  However, small recommendation, I'd always get the filtering done in the "Get" cmdlet if possible, plus UserPrincipalName is a Kerberos attribute, not the user's e-mail address; I believe that's in the mail attribute.